# Django admin filters on remote field via get_list_filter

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have 3 models, linked by FKs in a chain like this:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Order(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(
        'customer.Customer', on_delete=models.PROTECT)


class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    order = models.ForeignKey(
        'order.Order', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Now, if within my TaskAdmin, I use:

`list_filter = ('order__customer', )`

everything works fine. But if I go with:

```
def get_list_filter(self, request):
    return ('order__customer', )
```

the page loads, but as soon as I click on any possibile customer, a Bad Request (400) error page appears. It sounds like a Django bug to me, but maybe I'm doing something wrong here... any hints?

Comment: Do you mean by clicking on a customer trying to access the change_form for the customer? Did you check if the html behind the link is ok?

Comment: No, I mean by clicking on the customer filter and trying to only retrieve Tasks related to that Customer. I don't get what html I should be checking, Customer change_form works fine but it's not involved here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment, so I'll write here, even if this is not a *real* answer.

It looks there's an open ticket on this topic: [lookup_allowed fails to consider dynamic list_filter](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22569)

You can use two different workarounds to quickly solve this problem until it will be fixed upstream:

- in addition to `get_list_filter` you can define `list_filter = ('order__customer',)`, so that this field's lookups will always be whitelisted, even if not used (because get_list_filter has precedence)
- you can override `lookup_allowed` this way:

  ```
  def lookup_allowed(self, lookup, *args, **kwargs):
      if lookup == 'order__customer__id__exact':
          return True
      return super(TaskAdmin, self).lookup_allowed(lookup, *args, **kwargs)
  ```

  this explicitly allows the single lookup that will be used as url param.

Comment: I've tried the first option and it works nicely. If you define it outside the `get_list_filter` and later do some dirty tricks such as `return list + self.list_filter` it works since it has already been whitelisted. I can't see why this shouldn't be a good (and acceptable) answer then :)

Comment: The second approach worked for me well. Thanks